# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver even after unregistered

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-leaks, android-broadcastreceiver

Before marking it as duplicate, please read through full description (had bad experience this week).

Here is my code, to be sure I added registering and unregistering in all five methods.  myReceiver is a class level private non static member.

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        UnRegisterInternetBroadcast();
        storePreferences();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        RegisterInternetBroadcast();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        UnRegisterInternetBroadcast();
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        UnRegisterInternetBroadcast();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

I do not have `<receiver>` defined in my Manifest xml. All I have is below code to handle.

```
    public void RegisterInternetBroadcast() {
        if(myReceiver == null) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(getPackageName() + "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
            myReceiver = new InternetConnectionReceiver();
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
            myReceiver = null;
        }
        System.gc();
    }

    public void UnRegisterInternetBroadcast() {
        if(myReceiver != null) {
            myReceiver.clearAbortBroadcast();
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        }
    }
```

As per other articles over internet and questions in stackoverflow I should not be receiving any memory leaks. Any missing things in my code?
targetSdkVersion is 25 and I am testing in Marshmallow OS.

Regards,

Harsha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `myReceiver = null;` in `RegisterInternetBroadcast()` but that causes the `UnRegisterInternetBroadcast()` to fail, since the receiver is null.

Remove that line and it should work.

Comment: yikes... that's shame for me.. I meant to write them in UnRegisterInternetBroadcast() placed in totally wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You should unregister the service in onDestroy() method also.

Comment: yes.. code inside onDestroy() was length.. so I hadn't added in question.. now sensing its good to add..